# Scala indices of values in one list which are not in a second list

Tags: scala

I am trying to find the indices of elements in one Scala list which are not present in a second list (assume the second list has distinct elements so that you do not need to invoke `toSet` on it). The best way I found is:

```
    val ls = List("a", "b", "c") // the list
    val excl = List("c", "d") // the list of items to exclude
    val ixs = ls.zipWithIndex.
      filterNot{p => excl.contains(p._1)}.
      map{ p => p._2} // the list of indices
```

However, I feel there should be a more direct method. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems OK to me. It's a bit more elegant as a for-comprehension, perhaps:

```
for ((e,i) <- ls.zipWithIndex if !excl.contains(e)) yield i
```

And for efficiency, you might want to make `excl` into a Set anyway

```
val exclSet = excl.toSet   
for ((e,i) <- ls.zipWithIndex if !exclSet(e)) yield i
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be this

```
(ls.zipWithIndex.toMap -- excl).values
```

only works however, if you are not interested in all position if an element occurs multiple times in the list. That would need a MultiMap which Scala does not have in the standard library.

An other version would be to use a partial function and convert the second list to a set first (unless it is really small lookup in a set will be much fast)

```
val set = excl.toSet
ls.zipWithIndex.collect{case (x,y) if !set(x) => y}
```